# How do I disable GDM?

Tags: graphics, login, login-screen

The new Ubuntu features a completely unkillable GDM. Is there a way to disable it?

It is not enabled in services , the GDM startup script is deleted, it is removed from update.rc but it still starts up.

How do I disable GDM and Graphical User Selection?

Comment: The new Ubuntu meaning 16.04? Sorry, that is off-topic. Problems with it should be reported as bugs on Launchpad. Run `ubuntu-bug gdm`.